# Create a valid JWT Token for DocuSign API

Tags: c#, jwt, docusignapi

Ι try to create a valid jwt token

From settings i create an RSA keypairs and i get the private key without the "-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY----------END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
"

```
var rsaPrivateKey = @"MIIEogIBAAKCAQEAoGujdXbYVy68a4CSWz963SpYxVs20/..............HQ/jW8pFom6gJreCDkca5axYo/gXp3W3rQHFTkooTNbOk2MyFMZUqRD3aCG1wuUW3w8TgGX4slrLDV0pP4=";

var jwt = Sign(rsaPrivateKey);
```

I follow the instructions here https://developers.docusign.com/docs/admin-api/admin101/application-auth/ and after a lot of hours i create this method

```
    public string Sign(string privateKey)
    {
        List<string> segments = new List<string>();

        var header = new { alg = "RS256", typ = "JWT" };

        //For production environments, use account.docusign.com
        var payload = new
        {
            iss = "4f489d61-dc8b------a828-3992e670dcbc",
            iat = (Int32)(DateTime.UtcNow.Subtract(new DateTime(1970, 1, 1))).TotalSeconds,
            aud = "account-d.docusign.com",
            scope = "signature impersonation"
        };

        byte[] headerBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(header, Formatting.None));
        byte[] payloadBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(payload, Formatting.None));

        segments.Add(Base64UrlEncode(headerBytes));
        segments.Add(Base64UrlEncode(payloadBytes));

        string stringToSign = string.Join(".", segments.ToArray());

        byte[] bytesToSign = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(stringToSign);

        byte[] keyBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(privateKey);

        var privKeyObj = Asn1Object.FromByteArray(keyBytes);
        var privStruct = RsaPrivateKeyStructure.GetInstance((Asn1Sequence)privKeyObj);

        ISigner sig = SignerUtilities.GetSigner("SHA256withRSA");

        sig.Init(true, new RsaKeyParameters(true, privStruct.Modulus, privStruct.PrivateExponent));

        sig.BlockUpdate(bytesToSign, 0, bytesToSign.Length);
        byte[] signature = sig.GenerateSignature();

        segments.Add(Base64UrlEncode(signature));
        return string.Join(".", segments.ToArray());
    }

    private static string Base64UrlEncode(byte[] input)
    {
        var output = Convert.ToBase64String(input);
        output = output.Split('=')[0]; // Remove any trailing '='s
        output = output.Replace('+', '-'); // 62nd char of encoding
        output = output.Replace('/', '_'); // 63rd char of encoding
        return output;
    }
```

When i check the JWT validation in this tool https://jwt.io/#debugger-io, i get invalid signature error.

How can i fix the token  ?? I cant proceed with Step 2 Obtain the access token...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm sorry you having problems with JWT. I would recommend you use the DocuSign C# SDK instead of trying to write your own code.
Then you can find the example of how to use JWT here - https://github.com/docusign/code-examples-csharp.
The specific code relevant to JWT is here - https://github.com/docusign/code-examples-csharp/blob/38c2eb46948a3cbf55edcce758f88d775f80cae9/launcher-csharp/Common/RequestItemService.cs under the `UpdateUserFromJWT()` method.

Common problems with JWT:

1. Not obtaining consent.
2. Using public token instead of private.
3. Using malform token. Token must be exactly, including new-lines, as provided.
4. Not using correct UserId (GUID) in the request.
5. Not requesting "impersonation" scope in consent (#1 above).

Comment: Thanks !! I dont have users, my service call the api so i follow the Application Authentication Grant scenario https://developers.docusign.com/docs/admin-api/admin101/application-auth/. A service integration integrates directly with a DocuSign account and does not authenticate every end user. Instead, using this grant, the application itself is granted an access token and makes requests on its own behalf. How can i get jwt token to authenticate my application ?

Comment: I try the SDK and the RequestJWTUserToken method and now i get the access token !!! Thank you !!!